# Chromedriver 115 as trojan

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My issue with chromedriver 115 is that my company’s firewall detects it as a trojan malicious software, so even downloading it manually it won’t run. Did somebody have this issue? How to solve WITHOUT relaxing firm’s info security? Thanks.

I asked for my information security to download the zip through the new url. Then, they detected trojan behaviour in the executable. Now, i cant install it…

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please share the error log where it mentions _chromedriver 115 company’s firewall detects it as a trojan malicious software_

Comment: @undetected Selenium, the error is: "Microsoft Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk."

Also, I passed the chromedriver.exe on the site https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/, and it pointed "1 security vendor and no sandboxes flagged this file as malicious", with this vendor being "Gridinsoft (no cloud)" and its analysis as "
Trojan.Heur!.02052021"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are getting chromedriver from official trusted channels, such as directly from the Chromium Team: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

If you already have the latest version of `selenium` installed, it will automatically download chromedriver for you during your selenium tests. This may bypass standard firewall rules if your program language is already downloaded as a trusted program.

Eg, with `python`, this script will get `chromedriver` for you if it is not already installed:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried and did not work. This exact code you proposed brought "SessionNotCreatedException  -  Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.141 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Comment: What `selenium` version do you have? This is working on the latest version.

Comment: 4.12.0 (I just updated)